# Encrypt PDF file that contains an image only

Tags: c#, pdf, encryption, model-view-controller, itext

I am using iTextSharp to convert image files(.jpg, .png etc.) to PDF files. Now, there is a requirement to encrypt these PDF files without any password protection. I have tried the `writer.SetEncryption` method to encrypt the files, but when I open the PDFs from where they are saved in the directory, I can see their contents. Apparently, no encryption took place. [image: See the image: PDF file after encryption]. How can I get these PDFs encrypted?

```
public JsonResult ImagetoPDFOpenInDiv(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            string filename = file.First().FileName;
            string targetpath = Server.MapPath("~/Doc/");

            string filepath = targetpath + filename + ".pdf";

            using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                //Initialize the PDF document object.
                using (Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f))
                {
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create));

                    writer.SetEncryption(null,null,PdfWriter.AllowPrinting, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_256);

                    pdfDoc.Open();

                    //Add the Image file to the PDF document object.
                    iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(file.InputStream);

                    if (img.Width >= 585 || img.Height >= 830)
                    {
                        var scalePercent = (((pdfDoc.PageSize.Width / img.Width) * 100) - 4);
                        img.ScalePercent(scalePercent);
                    }

                    pdfDoc.Add(img);

                    pdfDoc.Close();

                    // Returning the virtual path of the pdf file generated.. in message.
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "/Doc/"+ trimFileName + ".pdf" });

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: is the expectation that the content would be encrypted? That the logo would be scrambled?

Comment: *"There is no encryption"* - that is incorrect. Even in your screen shot I see the SECURED writing indicating an encrypted file.

Comment: @AndréLemos yes..something like that. Is that possible?

Comment: @mkl yes..the SECURED indicates an encrypted file. But I can see the content of the file as it is.

Comment: @Novice101, so you want to encrypt the content before you place it on the PDF file (I guess?)? And then how would you extract the content and decrypt it?

Comment: *"yes..the SECURED indicates an encrypted file. But I can see the content of the file as it is"* - of course. You want "encryption without any password protection", so the default password is used, so any pdf viewer can decrypt without password input.

Comment: @mkl That means there is no point in encrypting a pdf file without password protection, as it will be decryted by any pdf viewer.

Comment: @AndréLemos I do not want to encrypt the data before placing it on pdf. As I have no idea right now, if it would be possible to extract the content from such pdf. I am asking if there is a way, I can encrypt the whole pdf file and not see its content as it is without decrypting it first.

Comment: @Novice101, what you can do is set the user password (not a owner password). You can also use a certificate (private/public key pair). The user password is set through the first argument on the SetEncryption method, but you will have to set a password. This will make so that the document is encrypted, and only a person with the password can open it.

Comment: @Novice101 *"That means there is no point in encrypting a pdf file without password protection, as it will be decryted by any pdf viewer."* - technically there is. A pdf needs to be encrypted (or signed) to set restrictions to what a user is allowed to do with the document. Encryption without password is a common way to allow for restrictions. Obviously, though, this only works with software that cooperates, the restrictions are not  strictly enforced.